# Increase performance of concurrent selects and updates

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I am writing an application. There are 30 threads which read one table for input. 
Eg.

```
Select top 1 name from table1 where flag != 1 order by mypriority
```

Now, as name is read, a bit column is updated to mark that the row is read. 
Eg.

```
Update table1 set flag = 1 where name = 'name'
```

The update statement is just after the select statement. 
The problem I faced it that many threads read the same row and thus process the same name which is repetitive work.

I tried :

```
Select top 1 name from table1 with (updlock) where flag != 1
```

This makes one row read at a time. And thread wait for one update to complete. So, that they can read next name. So, no benefit of multiple threads.

Can someone advice the best method/way to use.

Please ask, if my question is not very clear.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this "reading" one row at a time? Also, you have a query with TOP but not ORDER BY. This means that every time this query runs you might get a different value for the first row.

Comment: @SeanLange : I just added the order by. So these thread take one row do some processing and store the result in other row. This processing is like going to some site and getting data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use transactions to ensure each row is read once.

```
begin transaction t
Select top 1 name from table1 where flag != 1 order by mypriority
Update table1 set flag = 1 where name = 'name'
commit transaction t
```

The big issue here is that the processing time of each row by your threads seems negligible. If all your threads are doing is running those two queries in a loop, you will not gain any performance by using mutliple threads.

Is there a good reason to read only one row at a time ? Is there a good reason to use multiple threads ?
Please detail what you are trying to achieve.

**EDIT** You said that you are doing some processing with the record you are getting. How long does that processing takes in comparison to the execution of the two queries you presented ? If the processing time is less than the execution time of the queries, running more than two threads makes no sense.